# ¿Como obtener un bitmap de un ImageView cargado con Glide? Glide 4.9.0

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-glide

Necesito obtener el `bitmap` de un `ImageView` para luego guardarlo de manera local mediante un `FileOutputStream` y luego retomarlo cuando desee. El problema viene cuando trato de obtener el `bitmap` de dicha imagen pero me arroja un **NullPointerExcepcion**:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

Estoy utilizando la ultima actualización `Glide 4.9.0`.

Este es el código:

```
String url = getPreferences("URL");
                loadImagen(url);

private void loadImagen(String url) {
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url)
            .into(ImagenPerfil);

}

ImagenPerfil.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                ImagenPerfil.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = ImagenPerfil.getDrawingCache();
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                final byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
                try {
                    FileOutputStream outputStream = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("perfil.jpg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    outputStream.write(data);
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Antes me funcionaba por que obviamente le pasaba la imagen directamente obtenida de un `Intent` al escoger una de la galería del teléfono, pero ahora le estoy pasando una imagen a través de `Glide` con la **URL** de la imagen obtenida desde otra actividad y no se como hacerlo cuando es con una imagen cargada mediante una **URL**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de tanto buscar, encontré una forma muy sencilla de obtener el `Bitmap` de una imagen cargada mediante `Glide`.

```
private void downloadImage(){
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
            .asBitmap()
            .load(urlProfileImg)
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                   //Aquí obtengo el bitmap correctamente
                }
            });
}
```

Algo que me tenia confundido y espero que si alguien nuevo como yo se enfrenta a la misma duda es que primero se debe cargar la imagen normalmente con `Glide` y luego se realiza esta función por aparte para obtener el `bitmap`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes realizar es obtener el `Drawable` del `ImageView` para de esta forma obtener el `InputStream`.

Debes asegurar que se encuentra una imagen dentro del `ImageView`, entonces obtén el `Drawable`:

```
Drawable myDrawable = ImagenPerfil.getDrawable()
```

y posteriormente el Bitmap

```
Bitmap myBitmap = myDrawable.getBitmap();
```

---

En tu código se realizaría de esta forma

```
//Obtiene el Drawable del ImageView.
Drawable myDrawable = ImagenPerfil.getDrawable();
//Obtiene el Bitmap a partir del Drawable. 
Bitmap bitmap = myDrawable.getBitmap();

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
final byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: No me reconoce el `.getBitmap()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static byte[] toData(ImagenPerfil imagenPerfil) {
    Drawable drawable = imagenPerfil.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(drawable);

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
    return os.toByteArray();
}

public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if (bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }

    if (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```